# How to implement the magnifier glass on color picker of Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, colors, picker

It's the magnifier glass at the top left:

[image]

I've tried 2 methods, but both failed.

1. Once the magnifier glass is clicked, create a new cursor(a cursor with magnifier glass image, or a crossfair, whatever) and push it, then call 
   `nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` of `NSApplication` to eat all the events until 
   we get a `NSLeftMouseUp` event. It did works but not perfectly, other windows or apps will be ordered front when the click point is out of the origin window.
2. Create a NSColorPanel, try to send a fake mouse click event to the panel. It works on the color wheel, but has no effect once I change the event location to the magnifier glass button.

Question in [1]: How could I forbid all system mouse events dispatching until user clicks the left button?

Question in [2]: Is this possible?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @bneely, I think it's quite clear what he wants.  I'd guess that that magnifying glass is actually an opaque NSWindow that overlays the cursor (or the cursor image is popped to the crosshairs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz events service could be used if we want to block system events dispatching, but there are 2 problems with it:

1. Accessibility should be enabled by user;
2. Quartz event service is forbidden under sandbox.

It's impossible to make the method 1 succeeded.

Inspired by @CodaFi, I decided to use subclass of NSWindow to implement it. A sample project is created at gitbub https://github.com/wentingliu/ScreenPicker, go and check it out.

[image]